# How To Placehold Date Inputs With Today & Later

Tags: php, html, forms, date

I'm creating a form with two date selectors. Currently, they look like:

```
<input type="date" class="form-control" name="contract_start" value="<?php echo $contract_start; ?>">

<input type="date" class="form-control" name="contract_end" value="<?php echo $contract_end; ?>">
```

Right now, on the form, the default values for the date selectors just say "mm/dd/yyyy". I'd like to know how I can alter this so that the `contract_start` input is the current date, and the `contract_end` input is 10 months from the current date **by default**. How can I do this?

Comment: important note: `input date` does not support `m/d/Y`, only `Y-m-d`, at least on chrome. [check](http://codepad.viper-7.com/2trH58)

Comment: You are confusing placeholders with initial values. And if you mean just how to set initial (default) values relative to current date, you should show some effort in doing that and post the codee you have tried.

Answer (score 2):

Just set `$contract_end` to: 
 `date('m/d/Y', strtotime('+10 months', strtotime($contract_start)))`

First `strtotime` call will convert raw date to timestamp, second will add ten months to your timestamp, and `date` function will format it back.

[Strtotime reference](https://www.php.net/strtotime) 
[Date reference](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php)

Answer (score 0):

You can use a single strtotime() function also in date function like this :

```
<?php

    $contract_start = date('Y-m-d');
    $contract_end   = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($contract_start.' +10 months'));

?>

<input type="date" class="form-control" name="contract_start" value="<?=$contract_start;?>">
<input type="date" class="form-control" name="contract_end" value="<?=$contract_end;?>">
```